# C# MongoDB InsertBatch missing

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am learning from an old tutorial which uses the InsertBatch method but it's not found in the current version (2.6.0) of the MongoDB Driver.

Is it deprecated? Is there a new method? Is it just renamed?

Answer (score 0):

It is deprecated. [InsertMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) is the new method for this task.